# windows 10 -- something is disabling my wireless capabilty when ethernet connected

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

when connected to ethernet my wireless automatically disables.  i try to re-enable it but it quickly disables again.  went to bios and the power management setting for this is unchecked, so, it's not the issue.  i want wireless on at the same time to connect my wireless hard drive and wireless printer.  how to keep the wireless enabled when connected through ethernet? this is for WINDOWS 10 ONLY not 7

Comment: Windows has never easily allowed you use a wireless connection and a Ethernet connection at the same time

Comment: @Ramhound that's not true. It depends on the wifi card. On my laptop, with windows 10, I can use ethernet and wifi concurrently. I have an Intel NUC that can do it too.

Comment: Disable all third party/manufacturer utilities that start with your PC and try it again.  Lots of notebook manufacturers like to include a utility that will allow automatically disabling wifi when you plug in a network cable.  Beyond that, as-is there's not enough information to offer much more/specific advice (IMO anyway).